# Correct way to use a Timer to trigger NavigationView change in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have an app where I would like the user to be able to start a timed task, and when time runs out, the navigation hierarchy should pop and bring the user back. I have code that ~works, but I don't like the code smell. Is this the right way to approach something like this?

```
class SimpleTimerManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published var elapsedSeconds: Double = 0.0
  private(set) var timer = Timer()
  
  func start() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) {_ in
      self.elapsedSeconds += 0.01
    }
  }
  
  func stop() {
    timer.invalidate()
    elapsedSeconds = 0.0
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var timerManager = SimpleTimerManager()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(destination: CountDownIntervalView(
        timerManager: timerManager, length: 5.0
      )) {
        Text("Start the timer!")
      }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
  }
}


struct CountDownIntervalView: View {
  @ObservedObject var timerManager: SimpleTimerManager
  var length: Double
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
  var interval: Double {
    let interval = length - self.timerManager.elapsedSeconds
    if interval <= 0 {
      self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      self.timerManager.stop()
    }
    return interval
  }
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Time remaining: \(String(format: "%.2f", interval))")
      Button(action: {
        self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        self.timerManager.stop()
      }) {
        Text("Quit early!")
      }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .onAppear(perform: {
      self.timerManager.start()
    })
  }
}
```

I have a custom back button, which is something I'd like to preserve. My main concern is that it feels wrong to have code that stops the timer and pops the navigation inside a computed property. I'd prefer something like

```
Text("\(interval)").onReceive(timerManager.timer, perform: { _ in
  if self.interval <= 0 {
    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    self.timerManager.stop()
  }
})
```

inside `CountDownIntervalView`, but this generates a compiler error - `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate` - and, to be honest, I'm not sure *that* approach makes sense either (attaching the code that conditionally pops the navigation to a piece of UI). What is the "best practices" way of approaching this problem?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct CountDownIntervalView: View {
  @ObservedObject var timerManager: SimpleTimerManager
  var length: Double
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

  var interval: Double {
    length - self.timerManager.elapsedSeconds
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Time remaining: \(String(format: "%.2f", interval))")
        .onReceive(timerManager.$elapsedSeconds) { _ in
            if self.interval <= 0 {
              self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
              self.timerManager.stop()
            }
        }

    // ... other your code
```

Comment: Fascinating - I didn't realize I should treat `elapsedSeconds` like a binding there! I've accepted this as a solution because I assume you're endorsing the idea of attaching the pop code on the `Text` as opposed to somewhere else in the View. This still seems a bit suspect to me, but I'm willing to believe this is SwiftUI best practices.